# Visualizar en horizontal un select en html

Tags: html, css, html5, select, options

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
                            <select id="select_vista">
                                <option value="1">Lecturas</option>
                                <option value="2">Consumos</option>
                                <option value="3">Eventos</option>
                            </select>
```

Normalmente sale un desplegable, para poder seleccionar entre uno y otro.
Pero como hago si quiero que esas opciones estes abiertas y en horizontal, algo así ?¿

**LECTURAS | CONSUMOS | EVENTOS**

Y que tenga preseleccionado uno por defecto.
No se si es posible hacerlo con select y options, o tendría que usar listas y css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible, simplemente tienes que usar un inline-block en los options, usar el atributo selected en el option que desees para tener una opción preseleccionada, pero lo mas importante es usar el atributo, `size` el cual mostrara el numero de opciones que desees, es decir, las hara visibles por defecto.

```css
select {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding:10px;
  margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px;
}

#contentedor select option {
  display:inline-block;
}

#contentedor {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentedor">
  <select size="3">
    <option value="1" selected>Lecturas</option>
    <option value="2">Consumos</option>
    <option value="3">Eventos</option>
  </select>
</div>
```